# WrapGrid in ListView (without xaml) with C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Somebody know how to translate the following xaml code to C#?

```
<ListView>
     <ListView.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to create this in code, it would probably be better to just put the ItemPanelTemplate in a resource in your page or in App.xaml. 
Otherwise here how to create it by code:

```
ItemsPanelTemplate template=new ItemsPanelTemplate();
var str = "<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" 
     +"<WrapGrid Orientation=\"Horizontal\" />" 
     +"</ItemsPanelTemplate>";
ItemsPanelTemplate panelTemplate = (ItemsPanelTemplate)Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader.Load(str);

ListView listView=new ListView();    
listView.ItemsPanel = panelTemplate ;
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but currently I'm working with a MVP pattern (Model-View-Presenter), that mean that in this project I don't use xaml. My View is almost empty.

Thank you very much!

Comment: One thing, the last line of your code is wrong.

This should be so: «listView.ItemsPanel = panelTemplate;»
«instead of listView.ItemsPanel = template;»

Comment: MVP is not the recomended patern when using xaml, you should really consider switching to MVVM, it will make thing much more easier for you..

Comment: I know, but this proyect isn't up to me...
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemspaneltemplate) link what I conclude is that `ItemsPanelTemplate` belongs to mainly XAML because you can not alter them from simple run time APIs. So you need to stick to either XAML declaration or you can use `XamlReader` to load the XAML.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup;

private ListView GetListView()
{

    const string xaml = @"<ListView xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
                             <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapGrid Orientation=""Horizontal"" />
                                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                             </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        </ListView>";
    var lv = (ListView)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
    return lv;
}
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but in this case, it's not working for me, I need an completly C# solution without xaml.

Thank you very much!

Comment: As my answer says `Templates` belongs to XAML, I am desperately waiting for complete C# solution.